# Rethinkdb Scalability

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

How scalable is rethinkdb? Can it be used for TB's of data?

I have around 400 GB's of data, which are bound to increase by 10-25 GB's per week. Any suggestions, would be of great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rethinkdb is very scalable and you should be able to use it with TBs of data no problem, that's what its designed for. As for its stability it should be very stable as of version 2.0 and fully production.

http://www.rethinkdb.com/stability/

Comment: I agree completely, It's been more than one month, and my db is up and running smoothly

Answer (score 1):

Note that a NoSQL-Database does increase the amount of storage required massively, so be sure to have enough disk space on your nodes.

But some terabytes are no issue for RethinkDB, it's designed to handle a nearly infinite amount of data if your nodes have a lot of RAM it also provides nearly Memory-alike performance because the caching algorithms are very good.

You can easily spread out your data on many nodes, by sharding, which also increases the absolute throughput of your cluster, but slightly increases the latency of queries, because of the round trips between the cluster-members.